# Protein Mutual Information

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to find the mutual information (MI) between a multiple sequence alignment (MSA).

The math behind it is ok for me. Though, I don't know how to implement it in Python, at least in a fast way.

How should I compute the overall frequency `P(i;x)`; `P(j;y)`; `P(ij;xy)`. The `Px` and `Py` frequency is easy to calculate a hash could deal with it, but what about the `P(ij;xy)`?

So my real question is, how should I calculate the probability of `Pxy` in a given i and j column?

please note that MI could be defined as:

```
MI(i,j) = Sum(x->n)Sum(y->m) P(ij,xy) * log(P(ij,xy)/P(i,x)*P(j,y))
```

In which i and j are amino acid position in the columns, x and y are different amino acids found in a given i or j column.

Thanks,

***EDIT***

My input data looks like a df:

```
A = [
['M','T','S','K','L','G','-'.'-','S','L','K','P'],
['M','A','A','S','L','A','-','A','S','L','P','E'],
...,
['M','T','S','K','L','G','A','A','S','L','P','E'],
]
```

So indeed it is trully easy to compute any frequency of amino acid in a given position,
 for example:

```
P(M) at position 1: 1
P(T) at position 2: 2/3
P(A) at position 2: 1/3
P(S) at position 3: 2/3
P(A) at position 3: 1/3
```

How should I proceed to get, for example, P of a T at position 2 and a S at position 3 at the same time:
In this example is 2/3.

So P(ij, xy) means the probability (or frequency) of a amino acid x in a column i occur **at the same time** of a amino acid y in a column j.

Ps: for a more simple explanation of MI please refer to this link [mistic.leloir.org.ar/docs/help.html](http://mistic.leloir.org.ar/docs/help.html) 'Thanks to Aaron'

Comment: Are you doing this in pure Python or are you using some library on top of it, like pandas or scipy?  If you could be a little clearer about what your data looks like and the operations that need to be performed on it, that would help answering.

Comment: could you explain this problem for people who know nothing about proteins at all?

Comment: `x->n` is not a valid Python literal. What is that even supposed to mean? Also, what are things like `P(ij.xy)?` and `P(i;k)` supposed to mean? Your question sounds interesting but leaves out too many details for anyone but an expert in bionformatics to answer.

Comment: x -> n is not a literal but it means the variation of a given amino acid x to m, for example in a given column i there are these amino acids [A, S, T, K, L, P] so x could be any of these amino acids and the same for a given column j (that will have different amino acids) [A, S, T, L, P, Q] so y could be any of these amino acids.

Comment: What do you mean by `x to m`? I know what `1 to 10` means, but I don't know what it means to say that an amino acid is `x to m` What is `x`? What is `m`? `x` seems to refer to an amino acid, but what is `m`. It seems to be an int. Is it a column number? A frequency? Is `P(x->n)` supposed to be the frequency of `x` in column `n`? You need to explain your notation to people who don't already know what it means

Comment: Is your df actually just a single column of fixed length strings? (you could leverage that to speed up computation)

Comment: @Aaron Yes and no, I have actually a DF of dimension (sequence length) [in which, which amino acid is a column] x (number of sequences)

Comment: In your sample data you have a list of lists of length 1, where each of the inner lists is a single string. If instead the inner lists are themselves lists of 1-character strings, you could edit your post to make that clearer. Also, it wouldn't hurt to give a link: perhaps this?: http://mistic.leloir.org.ar/docs/help.html

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry, this was a little bit messy, x to m means the variation of an amino acid in a list of possibilities (See the edited question, hope it is more clear now...) for example in the column i there are m different amino acids [A, C, D, P, L, K] so x could be any of these amino acids, as well as y could be any of n amino acids in a column j

Comment: I added the `biopython` tag since if you do anything with bioinformatics and Python without reference to the libraries that have already been written then you run the danger of reinventing (in a sub-optimal way) a great many wheels.

Comment: I am still curious about how you intend to handle `'-'` in the formula. Are sequences which contain 1 or more `-` in the `i` or  `j` position ignored or are they somehow treated as wild-cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is correct (e.g., how is `'-'` supposed to be handled)? I assume that the sum is over all pairs for which the frequencies in the numerator and denominator inside the `log` are all nonzero and furthermore, I assumed that it should be the *natural* log:

```
from math import log
from collections import Counter

def MI(sequences,i,j):
    Pi = Counter(sequence[i] for sequence in sequences)
    Pj = Counter(sequence[j] for sequence in sequences)
    Pij = Counter((sequence[i],sequence[j]) for sequence in sequences)   

    return sum(Pij[(x,y)]*log(Pij[(x,y)]/(Pi[x]*Pj[y])) for x,y in Pij)
```

The code works by using 3 `Counter` objects to get the relevant counts, and then returning a sum which is a straightforward translation of the formula.

If this isn't correct, it would be helpful if you edit your question so that it has some expected output to test against.

**On Edit**. Here is a version which doesn't treat `'-'` as just another amino acid but instead filters away sequences in which it appears in either of the two columns, interpreting those sequences as sequences for which the requisite information is not available:

```
def MI(sequences,i,j):
    sequences = [s for s in sequences if not '-' in [s[i],s[j]]]
    Pi = Counter(s[i] for s in sequences)
    Pj = Counter(s[j] for s in sequences)
    Pij = Counter((s[i],s[j]) for s in sequences)

    return sum(Pij[(x,y)]*log(Pij[(x,y)]/(Pi[x]*Pj[y])) for x,y in Pij)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! It's so simple and very very Pythonic =]. the "-" is not so simple to handle, it works as a wild-card as you've said. For a huge MI in proteins we usually filter by a threshold. For example, if there are more than 10% of gaps ('-' stands for gaps in a multiple sequence alignment) we remove this column, otherwise keep it. In your code, if we remove every gap it will reduce the information. Another stuff if you want to use it later, it's very important to use frequency, so you have to divide by the number of columns. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a place to get started... read the comments

```
import numpy as np

A = [  # you'll need to pad the end of your strings so that they're all the 
       # same length for this to play nice with numpy
"MTSKLG--SLKP",
"MAASLA-ASLPE",
"MTSKLGAASLPE"]

#create an array of bytes
B = np.array([np.fromstring(a, dtype=np.uint8) for a in A],)

#create search string to do bytetwise xoring
#same length as B.shape[1]
search_string = "-TS---------"  # P of T at pos 1 and S at pos 2
               #"M-----------"  # P of M at pos 0 

#take ord of each char in string
search_ord = np.fromstring(search_string, dtype=np.uint8)

#locate positions not compared
search_mask = search_ord != ord('-')

#xor with search_ord. 0 indicates letter in that position matches
#multiply with search_mask to force uninteresting positions to 0
#any remaining arrays that are all 0 are a match. ("any()" taken along axis 1)
#this prints [False, True, False]. take the sum to get the number of non-matches
print(((B^search_ord) * search_mask).any(1))
```

Comment: Hi @Aaron, good approach, though it is not simple since I should try to 'guess' and put a input for string search in this method, see Dr. Coleman answer. I think (even though I haven't tested) Coleman's approach should be faster. But thanks for your effort and all the help

Comment: @kaihami I guess I wasn't entirely sure as to what you were looking for, but if you could enumerate the search strings, I can almost guarantee taking this approach or similar would be faster. the python `collections` library is made for convenience, not speed. Numpy utilizes significantly faster c libraries than anything in pure python.